# Possibly miss using if else statements in p5.js animation

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to get a line to snake down a canvas. I'm using if else statements, currently the line travels left to right, then down then right to left. But here I get stuck, it should go down again and then left to right again. not sure if I should be using functions?

Here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/makingsnippets/pen/gWeZPe?editors=0011)

```
function setup(){
  createCanvas(600,800);
    background(250,180,20)
}
function draw(){
  var left = 600;
  var right = 800;
  var speed = 3
  timeline.move()

}

var timeline = {
  speed : 3,
  x : 20,
  y : 20,
  move : function(){
    fill(0);
    ellipse(this.x,this.y,20,20)
    if(this.x<width-20){
      this.x = this.x + this.speed
    }
   else if(this.y > 0){
     this.y = this.y + this.speed}

 if(this.y > 100 || this.x < 20){
   this.y = this.y - this.speed
   this.speed= this.speed*-1
   this.x = this.x + this.speed+1}
     if(this.x < 20 && this.y > 200){

       this.y = this.y + this.speed
}
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use some kind of points or instructions instead of hardcoding the values. It would probably get much easier to build upon. You could also probably break down the movement part into more generic functions if you want.

Here is some modified code:

```
function setup(){
  createCanvas(600,800);
  background(250,180,20)
}

var points = [
 {x: 500, y:20},
 {x: 500, y:80},
 {x: 20, y: 80},
 {x: 500, y: 300}
]

var currentPointIndex =0;

function draw(){
  var left = 600;
  var right = 800;
  var speed = 3

  timeline.move()

}

var timeline = {
  speed : 5,
  x : 20,
  y : 20,
  move : function(){
    fill(0);
    ellipse(this.x,this.y,20,20)

    var didMove = false;
    var currentPoint = points[currentPointIndex];

    if(this.x < currentPoint.x - this.speed){
      this.x += this.speed;
      didMove = true;
    } 
    else if(this.x > currentPoint.x + this.speed){
      this.x -= this.speed;
      didMove = true;
    }

    if(this.y < currentPoint.y - this.speed){
      this.y += this.speed;
      didMove = true;
    } 
    else if(this.y > currentPoint.y + this.speed){
      this.y -= this.speed;
      didMove = true;
    }

    if(!didMove && currentPointIndex < points.length){
      currentPointIndex++;
    }
  }
}
```

It's quick and dirty, but shows the general idea. Hope it is helpful!

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for this, makes complete sense. I will try to create a function to populate the array so I don't have to hardcode the values

Comment: Hi, Markus, I wondered if you could explain how the x and y coordinates are being updated from the values in the points array?

Comment: Sure. So in the move function we will get the current point. currentPointIndex is set to 0, so the first point we will save as currentPoint is {x:500, y:20}. Look at the first if statement. if this.x (value 20) is less than currentPoint.x (value 500). This is true, and you add speed (value 5) to this.x making it 25. The reason why i use currentPoint.x - this.speed in the if statement is to make sure you dont miss the mark. This could be done in a different way